# How to run multiple mysql commands and then send response in express?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, npm, axios

I used mevn stack to make a website. But i use mysql as my website’s database.i use axios to interact with express backend. I want to handle multiple insertions in the same request.how can i achieve it.I have no problem with axios or frontend. This is sample idea i want do

```
app.post(“/api/xx”,(req,res)=>{
    1 . insert document to document table
    2 get inserted id
    3 insert any number of items to document_items table
    4 After completing all insertions send a success response. Otherwise send failed response
})
```

I try to use the await keyword. But i think its not work correctly in step 3
That steps i tried like following example

```
app.post("/api/eeee",(req,res)=>{
    var sqls = "insert into documents ( name) values ("+req.body.name+")";
    connection.query(sqls,(error,result)=>{
        if(error)throw error;
        var id = result.insertId;
        for(var i = 0 ; i < req.items.length ; i++){
            var sqp = "insert into doc_items(document,name)values("+id+","+req.items.name+");";
            con.query(sqp,(err,res)=>{
              if(err) throw err;
            });
        }
        res.status(200).send();
    });
});
```

How can i insert all data and send responses in express. I think that my code is not good for my needs??

Comment: The "M" in MEVN typically refers to MongoDB. Which MySQL library are you using?

Comment: i installed mysql libry using npm install mysql , version is : "mysql": "^2.18.1"

Comment: i know m is mongo db. but i want to use hogh relational database to my purposes. so i used mysql.

Comment: Would you consider migrating to a MySQL library that supports promises like [mysql2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2)?

Comment: its good idea, can i use both mysql and mysql2 libraries